# Pygame fade to black function

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I'm coding a game in python 3 using pygame latest version. I have a function that is intended to slowly fade the screen until it is totally black. It should do so by blitting a low-alpha black surface many times on the screen.

But when I test it, it only blocks the game until the loop is finished. I suspect a problem with the alpha of black_surface.

I've seen some questions on forums about fade in pygame, but none of them concerned fade directly in functions.

Here is the code:

```
def fade_to_black(screen):
    black_surface = Surface((screen.get_width(), screen.get_height()), flags= SRCALPHA)
    color = (255, 255, 255, 1)
    black_surface.fill(color)
    alpha_key = 1
    while alpha_key <= 255:
        screen.blit(black_surface, screen.get_rect())
        display.flip()
        alpha_key = alpha_key + 1
        time.wait(1)
```

I have looked in documentation and forums but can't find any solution. Hope it isn't an obvious issue I would have missed... Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a surface called `black_surface`, but you fill it with white. Fill it with black (eg. `(0, 0, 0, 1)`) and may work, but there's another problem:

When you call `display.flip()` inside a loop where you change the screen surface, the display may not actually update if you don't let pygame handle events (e.g. by calling `pygame.event.get()`), depending on your OS. Also, while your loop runs, you can't handle events manually, e.g. the `QUIT` event. So while your screen fades to black, you can't quit your game.

Generally, you should only have one main loop and not call blocking functions like `pygame.time.sleep`, but there are exceptions, of course).

Here's simple `Sprite`-based example:

```
import pygame

class Fade(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.rect = pygame.display.get_surface().get_rect()
        self.image = pygame.Surface(self.rect.size, flags=pygame.SRCALPHA)
        self.alpha = 0
        self.direction = 1

    def update(self, events):
        self.image.fill((0, 0, 0, self.alpha))
        self.alpha += self.direction
        if self.alpha > 255 or self.alpha < 0:
            self.direction *= -1
            self.alpha += self.direction

def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
    sprites = pygame.sprite.Group(Fade())
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for e in events:
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return
        sprites.update(events)
        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, pygame.Color('dodgerblue'), (100, 100, 100, 100))
        sprites.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

Comment: I understand better :) Thanks for your support!